# $\cot^{-1}\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} = 2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{3-4x^2}{4x^2}} - \tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{3-4x^2}{x^2}} $

Tags: trigonometry

> Express $$\cot^{-1}\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} = 2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{3-4x^2}{4x^2}} - \tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{3-4x^2}{x^2}} $$ as a rational integral equation between x and y.

This is what I've done:
Let $$t = \tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{3-4x^2}{x^2}}$$
$$2\tan^{-1}(t/2) - \tan^{-1}t = \tan^{-1}\frac{t^3}{4+3t^2}$$
$$\implies \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}{y} = \frac{t^3}{4+3t^2}$$

Substituting the value of t and squaring both sides leads to very long calculation. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: This may help $$\cos^{-1} \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=2\cos ^{-1} \frac{\sqrt {3} }{2x}-\cos^{-1} \frac {x}{\sqrt{3}\times \sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ Hoping no careless mistake.

Comment: It is $$\color{red}{\cos ^{-1} \frac{2x}{\sqrt{3}}}$$

Comment: @Mann Could you please describe in more detail how the above is useful?

Comment: @Mann Converting to $\cos^{-1}$ along with a bit of manipulation does reduce calculation but it's still quite a lot.

Comment: I believe the most compact relation between $x$ and $y$ is $y^2=3\left(x-\frac89x^3\right)^2$.

Comment: @DavidH Yup, that's correct.